# Pickling error-Cython with Pyspark: scikit-learn knn with user defined metric for large dataset

Tags: apache-spark, scikit-learn, pyspark, cython, knn

I wanted to use Cython with Pyspark to speed up Sklearn knn with user defined metric for a large dataset having 400000 rows and 65 columns. I have followed the instructions from [here](https://adventuresindatascience.wordpress.com/2016/04/02/integrating-spark-with-scikit-learn-visualizing-eigenvectors-and-fun/) and [here](https://www.4info.com/Blog/October-2014/Enhancing-Spark-with-IPython-Notebook-and-Cython). I am using Spark version 1.6.0 and python 2.7.13

I wrote the following code for a small sample dataset, but I am getting the following pickling error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/farzanadata/main.py", line 26, in <module>
bc_nbrs = sc.broadcast(nbrs)
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 741, in broadcast
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 70, in __init__
File "/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.7.0-1.cdh5.7.0.p0.45/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/broadcast.py", line 78, in dump
cPickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed
```

**spark_tools.py**

```
def spark_cython(module, method):
 def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
    global cython_function_
    try:
        return cython_function_(*args, **kwargs)
    except:
        import pyximport
        pyximport.install()
        cython_function_ = getattr(__import__(module), method)
    return cython_function_(*args, **kwargs)
return wrapped
```

**clinical_kernel.pyx**

```
cimport cython
from libc cimport math
cimport numpy as cnp
cnp.import_array()
def mydist(cnp.npy_double[:] x,cnp.npy_double[:] y):
  cdef double ranges[3]
  cdef int k
  cdef double out=0, out2=0
  ranges[:]=  [0.04028, 0.0983, 0.06602]
  for k in range(3):
      out += (ranges[k] - math.fabs(x[k] - y[k])) / ranges[k]
  for k in range(3,5):
      out2 += x[k]==y[k]       
  return (out+out2)/5
```

**main.py**

```
from __future__ import print_function
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from sklearn.neighbors import NearestNeighbors
import numpy as np
from spark_tools import spark_cython

import pyximport

conf = SparkConf().setAppName('Fibo')
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sc.addFile('file:///farzanadata/clinical_kernel.pyx')
sc.addFile('file:///farzanadata/spark_tools.py')
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
pyximport.install()
import clinical_kernel
df=sc.parallelize([[0.72694,1.4742,0.32396,1,1],[0.74173,1.5257,0.36116,0,0],[0.76722,1.5725,0.38998,1,0],[0.76722, 1.5725, 0.38998,0,1]])
X=np.array(df.collect())
mapper = spark_cython('clinical_kernel', 'mydist')
nbrs=NearestNeighbors(n_neighbors=4,metric=mapper)
nbrs.fit(X)
bc_nbrs = sc.broadcast(nbrs)
neighbors=df.map(lambda x: bc_nbrs.value.kneighbors(x,n_neighbors=4,return_distance=False))
neigh_df = neighbors.map(lambda x: x.tolist()).toDF(["neighbors"])
neigh_df.show()
```

Instead of broadcasting KNN tree, using the following code works perfectly which of course, is not ideal for large datasets.

```
neighbors=nbrs.kneighbors(X,n_neighbors=4,return_distance=False)
```

Using import dill as pickle did not help either

Answer (score 0):

changing sparktool.py the following way does the trick

```
def spark_cython(*args,**kwargs):
  global cython_function_
  module='clinical_kernel'
  method='mydist'
  try:
      return cython_function_(*args, **kwargs)
  except:
      import pyximport
      pyximport.install()
      cython_function_ = getattr(__import__(module), method)
      return cython_function_(*args, **kwargs)
```